# how do I query Sybase IQ server using odbc?

Tags: python, database, sap-iq

How can I query Sybase IQ server from a script such as Python or Perl using ODBC? I searched on internet but I couldn't find a sample connection string. Could someone provide a sample connection string for this?

the details i have for connection are server name and database schema name. (and username and password).

example using isql is

```
isql -S SERVER_IQ -D schema_name -U username -P password
```

Above connection works when i specify correct details. I need a corresponding connection string using odbc driver or Sybase IQ drivers.

Thanks.

Regards, Alok

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perl provides an easy to use interface which is not the same for Python on R. Anyways, i found the solution from our DBA. I use following connection string to open the Sybase IQ connection

```
"Driver={Sybase IQ};UID=username; PWD=*******; ServerName=SERVERNAME; CommLinks=SharedMemory,TCPIP{host=server.sg.planet.com;port=111}"
```

Regards,
Alok

Answer (score 0):

This may not be an answer, but I think it could qualify.

Why not use the native implementation for Perl?
http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.sqlanywhere.11.0.1/dbprogramming_en11/pg-perl.html

Comment: i have looked into the sybase documents. I couldnt find a valid example for sybase iq similar to so many examples on `www.connectionstrings.com` website.